# jQuery round / circle thermometer possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular progress indicator with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901603/circular-progress-indicator-with-jquery)

I've been hunting around on the net for hours now trying to find a jquery solution for a round progress meter / thermometer style plugin

[image]

i need to set a target say 2000 and then pass amount raised such as 100, it would then work out the % difference and show the progress on the image i attached, i.e the red lines would be the progress with 100% being all red like in image but if 50% for exmaple would be half red half black.

does anyone have any ideas if something liek this is floating around?

Comment: i saw that thread but thats a solid colour, i need to be able to do with the background image as custom graphics

Comment: I can't comment so forgive my 'answer' but couldn't you use the above example posted by @ Matt Ball and set a background image as above, use the CSS to overlay the image then reveal the image at the different intervals by manipulating the CSS in jQuery.

Comment: i cant actually see where the code / demo for that actually is on jquery, for the round one anyway

Comment: http://blakek.us/css3-pie-graph-timer-with-jquery/

Comment: that does not really work that well in IE9/8/7 so might give that one a miss :)

Comment: I find most animations run slower in IE especially 7 & 8 which is nothing to do with the framework or code it's too clunky, but you can adapt the principle if you don't get a better answer.

Comment: i looked at that other post but i cannot find anywhere in relation to how to make it work with the circular one, any ideas?? ive googled, looked at wiki, forums etc....